# How can I use C# code login ldap server access the company personnel list (AD account number, name, department) and other information

Tags: c#, authentication, ldap

I can login the Ldap Server with LdapAdmin,the following is its interface screenshot..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26Era.jpg)

but I simulatge this process through  C# code have error.do not know what the programe is

```
       private static void DirectoryEntryMethod()
        {
            string ldapPath = "ldap.corpnet.qushui:3269";
            string username = "aa";
            string password = "bb";

            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath, username, password, AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer | AuthenticationTypes.None);
            

            try
            {
                // 获取根节点
                DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

                searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.OneLevel;
                SearchResult searchResult = searcher.FindOne();


                Console.WriteLine(searchResult.Path);

            }
            catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException e)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);

            }
        }
``

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:“未知错误(0x80005000)”
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean findMoreThanOne)
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindOne()
```